# Scroll Bar not working in chatbox?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am working on chat box in angularjs and I want to add a scroll bar in the chat area so that Older chats can be easily seen by scrolling up...

```
    <div class="chat active-chat" id="scroll" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            <div ng-repeat="c in activeConversations track by c.time| orderBy:'time':false">
                <div class="bubble" ng-class="c.type">
                   {{c.message}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <span class="user_message">{{c.time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I already added the overflow property and only the scroll bar is visible but its not scrolling...
Is there anything i should change on controller side.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't see you limiting the height of the container anywhere. You need to set height on `#scroll` which is smaller than the actual height of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="chat active-chat" id="scroll" style="max-height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;">
    <div ng-repeat="c in activeConversations track by c.time| orderBy:'time':false" style="height:20px;">
        <div class="bubble" ng-class="c.type">
                       {{c.message}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="user_message">{{c.time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SachinBahal pls remove the classes chat and active-chat

Comment: @SachinBahal I think some of the property in classes overrides your code